# Implementing password toggling functionality

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
var pwd = document.getElementById('pwd');
var eye = document.getElementById('eye');
eye.addEventListener('click', togglePass);

function togglePass() {
  eye.classList.toggle('active');
  (pwd.type == 'password') ? pwd.type == 'text': pwd.type == 'password';
}
```

```css
.fa {
  position: absolute;
  left: 350px;
  top: 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #999;
}

.fa.active {
  color: #0000FF;
}
```

```html
<i class="fa fa-eye" id="eye"></i>
<input id="pwd" name="password" type="password" class="form-control" required autocomplete="off">
```

Until the `classList` toggling portion it is working - it turns the icon blue. However, it doesn't work for the portion on changing the password type to text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use single equal to for assignment `=`.

```
  (pwd.type == 'password') ? pwd.type = 'text': pwd.type = 'password';
```

```js
var pwd = document.getElementById('pwd');
var eye = document.getElementById('eye');
eye.addEventListener('click', togglePass);

function togglePass() {
  eye.classList.toggle('active');
  (pwd.type == 'password') ? pwd.type = 'text': pwd.type = 'password';
}
```

```css
.fa{
position:absolute;
 left:350px; 
 top:10px; 
 font-size:25px; 
 cursor:pointer; 
 color:#999;
}
.fa.active{
    color:#0000FF;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<i class="fa fa-eye" id="eye"></i>
<input id="pwd" name="password" type="password" class="form-control"  required autocomplete="off" >
```

Comment: Beware that changing the `type` of an `input` does not work reliably cross-browser.

Comment: ...although it looks like that may be just an IE8 and before problem (I decided to go double-check). Works on IE9+. If you don't need to support IE8 and earlier, just make sure you test on your target browsers.

Comment: `(pwd.type == 'password') ? pwd.type = 'text': pwd.type = 'password';` should just be `pwd.type = pwd.type == 'password' ? 'text' : 'password';`, there's no point in repeating it. (I know that the OP did that and you just fixed the `==`/`=` thing, but I'd probably point this out to the OP in the answer.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for your suggestions next time i will improve my answer

Comment: No reason you can't do so now. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the `type` of an `input` once it's been created reliably cross-browser. **Update:** That may be just an IE8 and before problem. If you don't need to support those, just make sure you test on your target browsers.

Instead, you'll have to create a new `input`, copy the `value` and a few other things over, and replace the original.

Roughly:

```
function togglePass(){
    var newpwd = document.createElement("input");
    newpwd.type = pwd.type == 'password' ? 'text': 'password';
    newpwd.value = pwd.value;
    newpwd.className = pwd.className;
    newpwd.id = pwd.id;
    newpwd.required = pwd.required;
    newpwd.autocomplete = pwd.autocomplete;
    pwd.parentNode.insertBefore(newpwd, pwd);
    pwd.parentNode.removeChild(pwd);
    pwd = newpwd;
    eye.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```js
var pwd = document.getElementById('pwd');
var eye = document.getElementById('eye');
eye.addEventListener('click', togglePass);

function togglePass(){
    var newpwd = document.createElement("input");
    newpwd.type = pwd.type == 'password' ? 'text': 'password';
    newpwd.value = pwd.value;
    newpwd.className = pwd.className;
    newpwd.id = pwd.id;
    newpwd.required = pwd.required;
    newpwd.autocomplete = pwd.autocomplete;
    pwd.parentNode.insertBefore(newpwd, pwd);
    pwd.parentNode.removeChild(pwd);
    pwd = newpwd;
    eye.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
.fa {
  position: absolute;
  left: 350px;
  top: 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #999;
}

.fa.active {
  color: #0000FF;
}
```

```html
<i class="fa fa-eye" id="eye">eye</i>
<input id="pwd" name="password" type="password" class="form-control" required autocomplete="off">
<div>x</div>
```

Comment: *(I forgot to copy the `className` over. If you don't see it above, hit refresh.)*

Comment: [You can](https://jsfiddle.net/bnavorej/) with `.setAttribute('type', ...)` - unless I'm not understanding what you mean? I think the real problem is the usage of `==` instead of `=` in the ternary within the question.

Comment: this function is not working

Comment: @chazsolo - Not cross-browser you can't. Some browsers allow it, but some don't (IE for one).

Comment: @Coder - I did say "roughly." :-) I'd forgotten to copy a couple of things, accidentally used `remove` rather than `removeChild`, and forgot `pwd = newpwd`. See the now-working example.

Comment: @chazsolo - I just had to go double-check, looks like they fixed that in IE9. Hopefully IE8 and before are dead enough now. So I'd just be sure to double-check it in browsers you want to support. :-)

Answer (score -1):

You can change **input attribute Type** using jquery.

```
$('#eye').click(function(){
    $('#pwd').attr('type','text');
});
```

It will show password in text form, you can also change it to password using same with    **type Password**.